# Elementary proof for Hilbert's irreducibility theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, galois-theory

I have tried to find a complete proof for Hilbert's irreducibility theorem, but everything I found was way beyond my level of understanding.

I am only interested in the simple case where the polynomial is in two variables over the rationals. Specifically, if $f\in \mathbb{Q}[T,X]$ be an irreducible polynomial, then there exist infinitely many $t_j\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(t_j,X)\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ is irreducible.

Is there a way to prove this using mostly elementary results?

Comment: Even the special case you want is not entirely "elementary", but you might try textbooks such as Volklein's *Groups as Galois Groups* or else Serre's lecture notes on Galois theory.  (Really old treatments are mostly in German, but are also probably more concrete than modern versions.)

Comment: P.S. Thoug I don't have a copy, there is a small expository book by C.R. Hadlock  which seems to do just what you want (4.2), in the old MAA Carus series: http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=5s1p0CyafnEC&oi=fnd&pg=PR9&dq=C.R.+Hadlock&ots=o17oC2it4Q&sig=An7qKP6YZ1AdjYCwnW3hF8w9w8o#v=onepage&q=C.R.%20Hadlock&f=false

Comment: This is probably too late now, but I explain Dörge's proof in detail in my *Field guide to algebra*.

Answer (score 3):

[Kaltofen's 1985 proof](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kaltofen/bibliography/85/Ka85_infcontr.pdf) ([Wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20170829092742/http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kaltofen/bibliography/85/Ka85_infcontr.pdf)) seems completely elementary *and* effective.

E. Kaltofen. *Polynomial-time reductions from multivariate to bi- and univariate integral polynomial factorization.* SIAM J. Comput., 14(2):469-489, 1985; DOI: [10.1137/0214035](https://doi.org/10.1137/0214035).

Comment: This is only for specializations from $n>2$ variables to $2$ variables. As the author himself points out (first sentence of the conclusion) the harder case of $2$ to $1$ variables over the integers is not covered by his argument.